# support for inherited tables in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Does [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) support inherited tables? I am using Postgres as DB

```
eg; var BaseTable = db.define('basetable', {
  createdBy: {
     type: Sequelize.String
  },
  modifiedBy: {
     type: Sequelize.String
  }
});
```

rest of the tables should inherit this basetable